# Why does this program that generates random numbers keep generating numbers in the hundreds?

Tags: java, arrays, math, random

I have a really simple question on arrays. I've been watching some tutorials and couldn't understand why the code below gives Frequency outputs as random combinations of 1**. It never gives numbers like 5, 67, 541 etc., it always gives something like 150, 175, 183 etc. I hope I made myself clear. Thanks alot!

Code:

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int freq[] = new int[7];

    for(int roll=1; roll<=1000; roll++){

        ++freq[1+rand.nextInt(6)];
    }

    System.out.println("Face\tFrequency");

    for(int face=1; face<freq.length; face++){
            System.out.println(face + "\t" + freq[face]);
    }
```

Sample Output:

```
Face       Frequency

1        176

2        171

3        157

4        159

5        164

6        173
```

Comment: This isn't so much an array question as it is a probability question.  It **could** give small numbers, it's just very unlikely.

Comment: It has to do with the random distribution of integers between 0 and 5 (1-6). Statistically they are all equally likely to happen if the randomizer is truly random, which is why you're seeing numbers that look like they might be "odd". Seeing a '67' for a 6 for example would indicate that a 6 was rolled only 67 times out of 1000, which isn't very likely. A weighted die for example might produce numbers that don't look normally distributed, in that, the probability of rolling a given number isn't the same as the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually more of a math question than a programming question!

There are six possible outcomes for the dice rolls and you roll the dice 1,000 times. That means that if you wanted to see a number that isn't of the form "one hundred and X," you'd need to either see 200 or more of one number or 99 or fewer of a number. The expected number of times you'll see each number is 1000 / 6 = 166.7, so in order to see 200 or more of a number you'd need to deviate by +33.3 or -66.7 from the true value. This can happen; it's just uncommon.

I wrote a program that simulated rolling dice like this until you got one of these types of rolls and counted how many times you'd need to roll the dice. After doing this 1,000 times, I found that on average, you need to roll the dice 53 times before you're going to see a number that isn't in the one hundreds. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class DiceRolls {
    /* The number of trials to run. */
    private static final int NUM_TRIALS = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int totalRuns = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TRIALS; i++) {
            totalRuns += runsUntilEvent(rand);
        }
        System.out.println(totalRuns / (double)NUM_TRIALS);
    }

    private static int runsUntilEvent(Random rand) {
        /* Track how many tries we needed. */
        int numTries = 0;
        while (true) {
            numTries++;

            /* Rather than indexing from 1 to 6, I'm indexing from 0 to 5. */
            int freq[] = new int[6];            
            for(int roll = 0; roll < 1000; roll++){
                ++freq[rand.nextInt(6)];
            }

            /* See if this isn't in the hundreds. */
            for(int face = 0; face < freq.length; face++){                
                if (freq[face] >= 200 || freq[face] <= 99) {
                    return numTries;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the answer to your question is "you may see it, but it's unlikely and you'd have to run the program a *lot* to see it."

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ohh i get it know. So it basically gives me the output of the "number of times a certain face appeared out of 1000 rolls". Like face 1 appeared 176 times and face 2 appeared 171 times etc. I thought program did something else. Considering from that perspective, like you said it is possible but very unlikely for a certain face to appear below 150 and above 200 and much more unlikely to appear around 5 times. Wow, I'm so dumb :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. A frequency of 5 would be very unusual because it would mean that number was only rolled 5 times out of 1000. The numbers you are getting are about 1/6 of the total 1000 rolls, so each of the six numbers are being rolled about one sixth of the time.

Comment: Thanks alot for the simple explanation, really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that you loop 1000 times the deviation is quite small.

If you loop only 10 times, but increase the numbers by 100 in the loop, you get a higher deviation.

Answer (score 0):

The output is the number of the times a number is found in each "dice roll". As far as you are using pseudo-random number generation, the number generation is considered as "fair", therefore you have a "fair dice roll", meaning that on average, every number has equal chances on each roll to appear.

Therefore, each number should have appear on average almost 1/6 times of the total rolls, which are the results you now have.

If you increase the number of the total rolls, the deviation of 1/6 between each number will be greater and increasing in analogy with the number of rolls.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your original question is why you are not getting low values like below 100 (less than 10%) or greater than 500 (greater than 50%).

Short answer, you were not lucky enough. Because the way you created your random generator, you have to run your program many more times to observe these values.

Let's calculate probability of any outcome (frequency) to occur in more than 50% cases if you run your program just once:
This can be easily estimated if we roll by pairs (e.g. 1000 rolls is 500 pairs)

For each pair, probability of some specific side (e.g. 6) is a number of qualified outcomes divided by total number of outcomes:

Qualified outcomes (for side 6 to occur in 50% rolls or more):

```
16, 26, 36, 46, 56, 66, 
61, 62, 63, 64, 65
```

Total outcomes: 6^2 = 36

So 11 qualified outcomes divided by total gives probability of one side to occur 50% time or more, which is **11/36**

Now we need this to happen N/2 times in a row, so we should multiply the pair probability N/2 times:  (11/36)^(N/2)

Wolfram alpha gives us 3.5 * 10^-258 which means you need to run your program 2.85 * 10^257 times to expect (once) a frequency of one specific side 500 times or more.

Divide that by 6 to see this for **any** side.